# The Chapel c_str() function seems to return a c_string

Tags: chapel

I'm new to the language, so perhaps I'm making a mistake, but this doesn't seem to work per the  documentation. The documentation states:

> **proc string.c_str():c_ptrConst(c_char)** Get a c_ptrConst(c_char) from a string. The returned c_ptrConst shares the buffer with the
> string.

But the following code produces a compiler error saying:

> c_str.chpl:6: error: cannot initialize 'str_ptr' of type
> 'c_ptrConst(int(8))' from a 'c_string'

```
use CTypes;

var a_str:string = "elephant";
var str_ptr:c_ptrConst(c_char) = a_str.c_str();
```

That error seems to indicate that a c_string is returned, but I also see in the documentation the c_string is being deprecated.

Thanks,

Gene

Comment: There have been some changes in this area as of last week's Chapel 1.32 release.  By any chance are you using an older version of Chapel (determined using `chpl --version` yet referring to the 1.32 documentation?

Comment: @Brad, I should have included that information. chpl version 1.31.0, and yes referring to the latest documentation. I just installed last week and assumed I had the latest version.

Comment: You're the unfortunate victim of bad timing I'm afraid: we just released 1.32 this past Thursday.  If you want to stick with Chapel 1.31, you can dial back to its documentation using this URL:  https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.31/ which documents `.c_str()` as returning `c_string`.  We deprecated `c_string` in the latest release since C doesn't really have a proper string type, so we're now representing such cases more like the `const char*` values they are.

Answer (score 2):

Chapel deprecated the `c_string` type in last week's 1.32 release in favor of `c_ptrConst(c_char)`, which is Chapel's transliteration of `const char*` in C.

It sounds like you got bitten by using an older version of Chapel in combination with the latest documentation.  Sorry for that confusion.  For reference, the documentation for `.c_str()` is at the following links for 1.31 vs. 1.32:

- 1.31: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.31/language/spec/strings.html#String.string.c_str
- 1.32: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.32/modules/standard/CTypes.html#CTypes.string.c_str

For anyone interested in more context for the change, or who has old code using `c_string` that needs updating, please refer to https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.32/language/evolution.html#c-string-deprecation for additional information.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I upgraded to 1.32 and it woks as expected.